# stoping iframe from reloading when I change pages

Tags: html, css, iframe

Is there any way for a iframe nested in a div on my page not to reload when I change pages in the nav? Because when I change pages it will load the code of the page and the iframe on the previous page will be reloaded. Is there any way that I can select it and make that it won't reload when I change pages?

Comment: What do you mean by 'change pages'? This implies your entire page is being reloaded, hence your iframe will naturally be reloaded because it is, in effect, an new iframe on a new page. Does you 'nav' reload the whole page or change the content dynamically with JS?

Comment: no it changes the whole page. hence thats what happens exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial reaction is: "Why the hell would you want to do that, it sounds awful?"

The only way for this to work is to change the page content dynamically, with the exception of the iframe, rather than loading a new page.
But to answer your question, yes you can do it.

If you have all the page content except the iframe inside a div, lets call it `#page` and the iframe is at the same level in the DOM, or higher, relative to #page, you could use something like jQuery's [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function to load new content for everything inside the #page div.

However, if SEO or Accessibility matter to you at all, you shouldn't do this.
A users browser will cache a lot fo the content in the iframe anyway, so it shouldn't be too demanding to reload it.

Comment: it does sound awfull because it is awfull. at a clients request he wants to put a audio streamer from another site and it work in a iframe. he also wanted to put it inside the actual page on a collum but then every time the page changes the obvious would happen the audio would stop streaming and restart.

Comment: Hmmm. If it was me, I'd try and convince them to go with a pop-out audio streamer, and use good examples like the one BBC Radio (http://www.bbc.co.uk/6music/) use to show how well it can work. You could use a play button or similar to call the popup, so it's only there when it's wanted.

And show whatever content you like in the popout. Any way you might get it to work the client's way, that I can imagine, will cause them too many problems.

Comment: yeah I was thinking about doing just that. thanks for ur answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you reload the entire page, the IFRAME element is getting reloaded with it. Unless you used AJAX or a second IFRAME, there is no way to have the whole page except one element reload.

Answer (score 0):

If the contents of the IFRAME are simple enough it might be a simple case of using some light query string parameters to indicate the state the IFRAME is in to persist it across pages.

Your options also depend on any development frameworks you might be using (.NET, Ruby, etc.).

Otherwise, additional IFRAMEs seem to be the only other solution.

Comment: I'd really like to know why a strategy employed by even Google, Microsoft, etc. for simple state persistence is down voted? Next time you use GMail pay attention to your browser URL. Perhaps not the perfect solution to the problem but given the vague details its a viable/valid option. Jeez.